# Proper JSON response for 3 table SQL query

Tags: php, sql, json, api

Im having trouble finding the best solution to solve this problem:

I have 2 tables,

```
TABLE order contains
  pickup_address,
  delivery_address
```

Both fields are foreign keys wich reference

```
TABLE address contains,
  id,
  city
```

Of course there are other columns but they are not relevant to the query at hand.
Basicly what I do is:

```
SELECT * from order LEFT join address ON (pickup = id) LEFT join address ON (delivery = id )
```

Something like that :) So i have a row that combines 2 addresses into the order. It's not a clean solution i think.

What im trying to do is let users query my API for this order, I'm not sure how i should return all the data.

- Do I return only the row of the order TABLE and let them ask my API again what the details are for each address_id?
- Do I return a full blown row with all tables combined?
- Do I seperate the order and addresses in JSON? Like so:

  ```
  {
  orders: [
  {
     id: "1",
     pickUpAddress: "1",
     deliveryAddress: "2",
   }
     addresses: [
   { 
     id: "1",
     ....
  },
  {
     id: "2",
  }
  ]
  }
  ```

  - Any other options?

Basicly i made the current JSON response, however im replying about 20+ orders every time. Is this efficient?

```
{
code: 200,
data: {
orders: [
{
id: "1",
customer_id: "cust1",
reference: "asdfad",
state: "4",
pickUpAddress: "1",
pickUpDate: "2012-02-21",
deliveryAddress: "2",
deliveryDate: "2012-02-23",
pickup_street: "street 1",
pickup_housenumber: "1",
pickup_country: "belgium",
pickup_zipcode: "1000",
pickup_city: "brussels",
delivery_street: "street 2",
delivery_housenumber: "2",
delivery_country: "belgium",
delivery_zipcode: "1000",
delivery_city: "brussels"
}
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would return all the data, unless there are reasons for not doing so (massive amounts, for instance).
Why would you not?

I would, however, also allow them to get the address by ID. Give them as many options as you can.

Comment: Edited my org post. Would this be efficient?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether it could be _more_ efficient. Is the user going to need all those details all the time? If so, may as well provide them. If she is only going to need to view the addresses for one order at a time, then let her make two separate calls.

Comment: Well im not sure what i want. If i get them all at once the user only has to wait 1 time. If i get them when the user selects the order id i have to resync and he has to wait every time.